# Where did my Apple TV wish list go?

Tags: appletv

Since updating to iOS and tvOS 17.2 I've been unable to find my wishlist. I've assumed that it was just the usual sync delay with my AppleID following an update and that the wishlists would eventually reappear — and that Apple would also eventually remember who I was and stop featuring so much sports — but enough time has passed that I'm beginning to wonder: are wishlists gone? (Not possible I know, but — worth asking.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the great bit bucket in the cloud.

https://www.macrumors.com/2023/12/17/apple-removes-tv-show-movie-wishlists/

Wishlists are gone it seems.

Comment: WTAF? What were they thinking? And it looks like a similar mess in Books: My current activity has overtaken by promotions for books I'm never going to read. (This is nuts, after decades or book and movie recommendations failing to come up with any useful suggestions, Apple's solution is to  — make those recommendations even more prominent and hide the list of things I actually want to watch?)